# DOM elements update very slowly

Tags: javascript, function, performance, dom, event-handling

I'm writing this beginner rock-paper-scissors game. Added event listeners. Somehow it works very strangely.

When I click on weapons with approximately 2s delay or more between each click - it works fine, but when I click really fast on them then my player's weapon and scores update really slow or sometimes don't event update and nothing changes.

I've tried replacing variable declarations in code from global scope to function scope and it still works the same.

```js
const weapons = document.querySelectorAll(".weapons__img");
const playerWeaponSpan = document.getElementById("playerWeapon");
const computerWeaponSpan = document.getElementById("computerWeapon");
const playerScoreSpan = document.getElementById("playerScore");
const computerScoreSpan = document.getElementById("computerScore");

let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

const getComputerWeapon = function() {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
  if (randomNum <= 5) {
    return "rock";
  } else if (randomNum <= 10) {
    return "scissors";
  } else if (randomNum <= 15) {
    return "paper";
  } else {
    return "ERROR";
  }
};

weapons.forEach((weapon) => {
  weapon.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const playerWeapon = weapon.id;
    const computerWeapon = getComputerWeapon();
    if (playerWeapon === "paper" && computerWeapon === "rock") {
      playerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Paper";
      computerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Rock";

      playerScore++;
    } else if (playerWeapon === "paper" && computerWeapon === "scissors") {
      playerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Paper";
      computerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Scissors";
      computerScore++;
    } else if (playerWeapon === "scissors" && computerWeapon === "paper") {
      playerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Scissors";
      computerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Paper";
      playerScore++;
    } else if (playerWeapon === "scissors" && computerWeapon === "rock") {
      playerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Scissors";
      computerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Rock";
      computerScore++;
    } else if (playerWeapon === "rock" && computerWeapon === "scissors") {
      playerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Rock";
      computerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Scissors";
      playerScore++;
    } else if (playerWeapon === "rock" && computerWeapon === "paper") {
      playerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Rock";
      computerWeaponSpan.textContent = "Paper";
      computerScore++;
    }
    playerScoreSpan.textContent = playerScore;
    computerScoreSpan.textContent = computerScore;
  });
});
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1 class="header__heading">Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors Game</h1>
  <p>In order to win you need to score up to 5 points</p>
  <p>Pick one of three weapons:</p>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <section class="weapons">
    <div class="weapons__images">
      <img src="https://mgarcia-rps.netlify.app/Paper_1.png" alt="Image #1" id="paper" class="weapons__img" />
      <img src="https://mgarcia-rps.netlify.app/Scissors_1.png" alt="Image #2" id="scissors" class="weapons__img" />
      <img src="https://mgarcia-rps.netlify.app/Rock_1.png" alt="Image #3" id="rock" class="weapons__img" />
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="score">
    <div class="score__text">
      <div class="score__numbers">
        <p>
          Player <span id="playerScore">0</span> &mdash;
          <span id="computerScore">0</span> Computer
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="score__weapons">
        <p>Player's Weapon: <span id="playerWeapon">?</span></p>
        <p>Computer's Weapon: <span id="computerWeapon">?</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work absolutely fine in the snippet I created in the question - even when clicking like a mad man. Can you please be more specfic about the steps required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: yea I see no problems either, and looking at the code I can't imagine what would be consuming any time inordinately.

Comment: Looks fine, maybe adding `draggable="false"` to the images so you don't accidentally drag. But that shouldn't hurt performance

Comment: i forgot to add css snippet in the question. images have some animation that lasts 0.3s when they're hovered. idk maybe that's the problem. it's like when i'm clicking really fast on all of them in a row player's and computer's weapons and scores update slowly. like when i click on scissors and then quickly on rock it doesn't update to rock instead it updates to scissors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem i see in the code is that you do not handle the case where the computer and the user choose the same weapon.

So whenever they "tie" the UI does nothing and looks like the click did not happen.

Comment: yes thank you i completely forgot to write code for this scenario. there was actually one more problem besides this. images needed the attribute's "draggable" value set to false so that i don't accidentally drag an image when fast clicking.